# Predicting the snow line in the French Alps

Tags: france, hiking, alps, snow

I'll be trekking in and around the French Alps in the end of April (around the time the snow is melting).  A lot of the trails are going to be snowy at this time, especially above 1000m

I'm not looking for a product recommendation, but where should I start in estimating the snowline at this time of year (this will dictate kit necessary and routes available)?

Some additional notes:

- I have considered using temperature, but this will not be reliable (often hot in ski resorts during the day around this time but still plenty of snow).
- I realise this will be different depending on the year's snow conditions/temperature/weather

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: I don't see how anyone could begin to answer this. Are you asking for a weather forecast 3 months ahead?

Comment: You can likely google what past conditions are and prepare for the average predictions. https://www.igluski.com/snow-history

Comment: You’ll probably have a very different results on the north and south sides of a valley, won’t you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on too many variables - the overall snowpack, the duration of snowstorms between now, the duration and depth of cold snaps, cloud cover (10 C on a cloudy day melts much less snow than 10 C on a sunny day)... all you can really do is look at historical norms to get a sense of what your probabilities are.